# After migrating account with Mojang, where are my new/current saves?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Recently I migrated my account on Minecraft.net. 
I had two worlds/saves before migration called 'Exile' and 'TEST world'.

A little after I migrated, I deleted 'Exile' and 'TEST world', and started a new world/save called 'Village on the Green'.
Today, I went in my saves to check out my files for ADMIST related purposes. 
'Village on the Green' wasn't in the saves, but my old maps 'Exile' and 'TEST' world were, even though I had deleted them.

I don't care about the latter, I think I get whats going on there. The problem is that since migration, I cannot find my current worlds/saves.

Where are they at? Is there still local content for my current worlds in a file somewhere, or does Mojang hold onto all of the data now?

4/4/2013 EDIT: *Most likely location conflict.*

Comment: Mojang never has the world for your saves.

Comment: @pppery This is not a duplicate of that question. The other question asks, where the default save loaction for minecraft worlds is. This question specifically states that the world save data is NOT in the saves folder and asks, where the data could be instead.

Answer (score 3):

The account migration process does not change where your Minecraft saves are kept; whatever this problem is, it is unrelated.

I noticed you mentioned `bin`. Saves are not kept in `.minecraft\bin` but in `.minecraft\saves`.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I don't know why in the heck I mentioned minecraft/bin (edited out now). 
My save folder in the normal spot as roaming/minecraft/saves, but like I mention above, only has Exile (and Exile-), which have long since been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Where is your Minecraft folder? If you're on a PC, the one created by the official Minecraft launcher is always in `\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft`, and you'll find your world saves in `\saves`.

I'm guessing your old worlds are in some other Minecraft directory elsewhere on your system?

Comment: My Minecraft folder is in the right spot, but you gave me an idea. I _was_ doing a lot of mod installing at one point, so I kept moving the Minecraft data around to keep it backed up and had it working from different spots. I thought I cleaned all of that up, but that was a while ago so I might have some location conflict going on. Thanks for the input.