# suddenly can't get into minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

One day I opened Minecraft, pressed play, chose multiplayer and instead of opening, it gives the message "searching for network"  It stays on this message with three little circles above it moving indefinitely.  My internet connection is working fine and I didn't change any settings.  Can anyone help with this?  If I uninstall from my computer and re-install to try and fix the problem, I will loose everything I worked for.

Comment: You can actually back up your saved worlds and restore them after reinstalling

Comment: and how do I do that exactly

Comment: check out this answer for the location of the files http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/113238/26487 then copy the save to another location and copy it back when done

Comment: Don't do that! Your Minecraft is fine and doesn't need to be reinstalled. You just pushed a different button, and need to push the other button instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is very normal. If you would like to connect to a server, you should add a server or use direct connect. If you want to get to your normal worlds, go to single player instead of multiplayer.

If you made things on multiplayer (servers) then uninstalling would change nothing except for removing servers and removing your saved username and password. If you have single player worlds, it would delete them (depending on how you uninstall, they could stay the same).

Comment: thx dood that helps alot

Comment: @Colby If this solves your problem, consider upvoting it and giving it the checkmark.

Answer (score -1):

Considering the time at which this question is being asked, it's likely that you are being affected by an outage occurring on Minecraft's session servers.  Most multiplayer servers require a valid minecraft account, and they check with the login servers to see that your account is valid.  If the login servers cannot be reached, then your attempt to login will fail.

To find out about the status of the servers needed to perform this check, visit https://help.mojang.com/.  At the this writing, they are currently experiencing an outage.  You should still be able to play single player in an offline capacity.

Comment: Yes, this is currently happening. There are updates at https://help.mojang.com/

Comment: Yes this is happening, but it's irrelevant to their problem. They tried to play Singleplayer but clicked Multiplayer and got confused. Since they can click Multiplayer, they have already logged in without trouble.

Comment: From the question: "I opened Minecraft, pressed play, chose **multiplayer**" empahsis, mine, though.

Comment: @Token Yeah, you can't choose multiplayer until after you've successfully logged into the launcher and it's started the game.